# MySQL - Selecting the latest records before a given date in a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

Bear with me, I'm new to SQL and am having trouble explaining this...

I have two tables similar to the following:

```
test1
+------+----------+----------+-----------+
|  id  |  serial  |  t1data  |  t1date   |
+------+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1   |    a     |   ...    |  6/02/12  |
|  2   |    a     |   ...    |  6/04/12  |
|  3   |    b     |   ...    |  6/06/12  |
|  4   |    a     |   ...    |  6/08/12  |
+------+----------+----------+-----------+

test2
+------+----------+----------+-----------+
|  id  |  serial  |  t2data  |  t2date   |
+------+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1   |    a     |   ...    |  6/05/12  |
|  2   |    b     |   ...    |  6/07/12  |
|  3   |    b     |   ...    |  6/08/12  |
|  4   |    a     |   ...    |  6/09/12  |
+------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to create a query to join the two tables so that each record in `test2` corresponds to latest `test1` record that occurred prior to the date of `test2`. Any given serial can have multiple records in either table.

Using the above example the result should look like this:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|  serial  |  t2data  |  t2date   |  t1data  |  t1date   |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|    a     |   ...    |  6/05/12  |   ...    |  6/04/12  |
|    b     |   ...    |  6/07/12  |   ...    |  6/06/12  |
|    b     |   ...    |  6/08/12  |   ...    |  6/06/12  |
|    a     |   ...    |  6/09/12  |   ...    |  6/08/12  |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

This is the query I tried but it does not work.

```
SELECT 
    t2.serial, t2.t2data, t2.t2date, t1a.t1data, t1a.t1date
FROM 
    test2 t2
JOIN 
    test1 t1a ON (t1a.serial = t2.serial AND t1a.t1date > t2.t2date)
LEFT JOIN 
    test1 t1b ON (t1a.serial = t1b.serial AND t1a.t1date < t1b.t1date)
WHERE 
    t1b.serial IS NULL
```

I may be going at this all wrong but what can I do to make this work?

Comment: you have not given alias 't1' to any table and specified in select

Comment: @BhavikShah That was a typo. I have fixed it now.  It is not the problem I am having though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it's working:

```
SELECT t2.serial, t2.t2data, t1.t1data, t1.t1date
FROM
  (SELECT t2.serial, t2.t2data, t2.t2date,
         (SELECT max(t1date)
            FROM test1 t1
           WHERE t1.serial = t2.serial
             AND t1.t1date <= t2.t2date) AS t1date
  FROM test2 t2) t2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
   test1 t1 ON t2.serial = t1.serial AND t2.t1date = t1.t1date;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/215c263/2

Comment: This does work but it seems like there should be a better way.  I also got it to work by creating a view with a join and joining to itself.  Performance wise, the two seem to be equally as slow with 1000's of records.