# MySQL: Find most recent row in one table for each row in another table containing a specific date

Tags: mysql

Having a hard time creating a mysql query to do the following.

We have a list of staff with columns as follows:

```
eg: employee table
name    em_date   (other cols)
Fred    1-1-1960
Fred    1-1-1970
Fred    1-1-1980
John    1-1-1960
John    1-1-1990
```

We have a second table containing family details:

```
Partners table
name       marriage_date     partner_name     (other cols)
Fred       1-1-1959          Sue
Fred       1-1-1969          Marg
John       1-1-1985          Joan
```

I'm trying to generate a table containing:
name, employment_date, marriage_date, partner_name

Some staff have been employed multiple times (think contractors) so they have multiple employment dates. Some of them have also remarried and so have different partners at different times (and/or may not have been married at some time)

I need the output to show the partner at the time of their employment.

The output should be:

```
name       em_date      mar_date     partner_name
Fred       1-1-1960     1-1-1959     Sue
Fred       1-1-1970     1-1-1969     Marg
Fred       1-1-1980     1-1-1969     Marg
John       1-1-1960     null         null
John       1-1-1990     1-1-1985     Joan
```

I was certain I could use the SQL from the link below, but alas I am unable to resolve it
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27823/query-to-find-closest-lesser-date

Any pointers greatly appreciated - I'd include what I've tried but I've tried too much and it's just not working. I either get the cartesian product or a single row.

There are keys on name and the 2 dates, but no others (ie:there is no id linking the employee to their partner at the time of their employment [think importing old data after the fact...]), hence I have to search by name and match the nearest partner based on the calculation:

```
min(employment_date - marriage date)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: primary key for employee table is combination name,employment date. PK for partner table is combination name,marriage date. If I could change it, I would....

Had to edit as I'm a new user and cannot coment yet...

Edit: sqlfiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84148/2

Comment: Don't you have any primary key in your employee table because there are 2 records of john but its hard to relate the associated record for john1 and john2 in Partners table

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly I was able to stumble across something similar enough to my question that I was able to solve it.  Thanks to all who contributed.

Here is the solution that I have found:

```
select t2.emp_name, t2.start_date, t1.spouse_name, t1.mar_yr
from
    ( select t2.emp_name, t2.start_date, 
        ( select max(mar_yr)
          from   partners t1
          where  t1.emp_name = t2.emp_name
            and  t1.mar_yr <= year(t2.start_date)
    ) as mar_yr
  from employees t2) t2
left outer join
    partners t1 on t2.emp_name = t1.emp_name and t2.mar_yr = t1.mar_yr;
```

SQLFiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84148/13

It produces exactly what I needed. Thanks to all who contributed and apols for not locating the solution earlier, which btw, was here:
[MySQL - Selecting the latest records before a given date in a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971816/mysql-selecting-the-latest-records-before-a-given-date-in-a-join)